# QT Creator C++ : Compile executable for linux

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a GUI program in QT Creator with C++ and I already compiled for windows and it's working nice.
But I went to test it on linux but obviously it didn't work because linux doesn't open .exe files.
So my question is how can I set QT Creator to compile for linux extension in order to my program works there? Or how can I do that?

Comment: It's unclear from your question, are you saying that you're doing this on MS-Windows, and you are asking how to cross-compile for Linux? Are you aware that you need to install all Linux libraries and header files, in order to be able to cross-compile, as I believe you're asking? Do you have them installed?

Comment: Linux doesn't typically have a specific extension for executables. And the process to creating an executable on a linux machine is roughly the same as it is for windows, but done on a linux machine.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik:
Yeah basically that's what I want, sorry for not explaining well. I don't have those libraries and headers, where can I get it? And how work with it?

Comment: Alexpdev: so do I need to install QT Creator on linux to compile my program?

Comment: @Harry  Only if you wanted to compile it in the same way.  There are other ways to compile a program.  There are actually multiple ways to compile it within qtcreator.  But since you already know how to do it with qtcreator on windows you might as well do the same on linux. that is my opinion anyway

Comment: I'm certain that the QT creator community have their own forums and mailing lists, a far more likely place to get more information help with this highly-specific question, than a general programming site like Stackoverflow. You'll also need a cross-compiler too, the compiler must also be capable of producing a linked ELF executable. Honestly, it will be faster for you to simply install Linux and build natively there, then to suffer through this.

Comment: I already have linux in dual boot in my pc. As well I just finish the instalation of QT Creator on linux i will test it now

Comment: I'm now stucked to compile it. Already done it. While in Windows I type "windeployqt.exe --quick .", what do I do in Linux?

Comment: You just run the executable? If it compiled and linked correctly, it should exist and be able to run.

Comment: I can open the executable but I can open it because it was compiled in this folder. If I send it for another person, they won't be able to open it because of missing libraries.
That's what happened with windows version. I compiled but I had to make that windeployqt in terminal in order to create a new executable with all needed libraries to run in other computers.
No?

Comment: @Harry On Linux you need to create an [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) from your application executable. Then you can distribute it to everyone and they can simply run it without installing any dependencies.

Comment: Ahh I see, yes then Aamir's suggestion is one way of achieving that. There is no official Qt deployment tool for linux.